# ASIHTTPRequest didReceiveData - how to use?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I want to download a file using ASIHTTPRequest, and I want it to behave like a regular direct-to-file download, except I want to encrypt the data as it comes in.

Because I need custom data handling, I need to have my delegate implement request:didReceiveData, and I found out that: "ASIHTTPRequest will not populate responseData or write the response to downloadDestinationPath - you must store the response yourself if you need to."

I can't find any examples of code that implements a custom didReceiveData, I'm not sure how to handle data as it comes in or how to set the download destination path.  Is there example I can look at online?

To write data to a destination file I tried to define the function as simply:

```
-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [data writeToFile:request.downloadDestinationPath atomically:YES];
}
```

But when the request is complete, the file doesn't exist, verified by:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest* req in queue.operations) {
    NSLog(@"file at %@", req.downloadDestinationPath);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:req.downloadDestinationPath]) {
        NSLog(@"file exists!");
    }
}
```

If anyone has experience with this library and could point me to a resource, example project, tutorial, or just has a simple answer, I would much appreciate it :)

EDIT: would it be better to use NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library comes with a sample project